# Create a submatrix of UpperTriangularMatrix in Julia

Tags: julia

Given a list of columns and rows, I want to produce a submatrix of a cholesky factorization. Example:

```
julia>  A = rand(10,10)
julia>  R = chol(A'*A)
julia>  ind = [1,3,6,8,9]
julia>  R[ind,ind]
```

However, this results in an error:

```
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 5x5
UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:
 1.28259  0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0      6.51646e-314  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0      0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0      0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0      0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
at index [2,1]
in _unsafe_getindex at multidimensional.jl:197
in getindex at abstractarray.jl:483
```

I understand that this would work for a typical matrix, but the `UpperTriangular` type obviously requires something different... I can't find documentation on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Triangular matrices haven't been updated to take advantage of fallback non-scalar indexing in 0.4 (this was a missing method error in 0.3).

Easiest ways around this for now are conversion to a full array before you index:

```
julia> full(R)[ind,ind]
5x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.2261  1.28096  1.69087    1.26135    1.50703
 0.0     1.03681  0.115735   0.559855   0.70766
 0.0     0.0      0.702936  -0.111155  -0.61263
 0.0     0.0      0.0        0.661491   0.33661
 0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0        0.159691
```

Or by using a SubArray, which creates a view into the original data (so modifications will propagate):

```
julia> sub(R, ind, ind)
5x5 SubArray{Float64,2,UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}},Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},0}:
 2.2261  1.28096  1.69087    1.26135    1.50703
 0.0     1.03681  0.115735   0.559855   0.70766
 0.0     0.0      0.702936  -0.111155  -0.61263
 0.0     0.0      0.0        0.661491   0.33661
 0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0        0.159691
```

Comment: So I would do `UpperTriangular(full(R)[ind,ind])` if I plan to use the submatrix for further computations? This seems inefficient (in practice I have a large matrix `R`)...

Comment: The `Triangular` types are simply wrappers around full matrices.  They just tell Julia to ignore all elements above or below the diagonal.  Re-wrapping the result does not copy the underlying data, so it's not really all that inefficient.

Comment: Nice! That is good to know. Maybe I should be looking into storing this as a Sparse, UpperTriangular matrix then... I had assumed the lower diagonal zeros weren't stored in memory by default.

Comment: Even though that will take less memory, I have a feeling it'll be way slower in most uses.